# Error launching Analytics for Apache Hadoop: "Could not initialize class com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.blumix.oauth2.intg.OAuth2ExtURLAccessHandler"

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, analytics-for-hadoop

Error launching Analytics for Apache **Hadoop** in **Bluemix**. I'm getting the following error:

> Could not initialize class com.ibm.datatools.dsweb.blumix.oauth2.intg.OAuth2ExtURLAccessHandler.

I tried to restart the service, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to open a support request using one of the following methods:

- Use the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
- Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.